# NoClassDefFoundError for com/sun/istack/logging/Logger in Glassfish v3

Tags: glassfish, jax-ws, classloader, glassfish-3

I have an application client which calls a SOAP service. I've used wsimport from the glassfish distribution to generate the ws classes, and everything works fine in Glassfish v2. When I run it (webstart) from v3, the app runs fine, but when I initiate a SOAP call, I get

```
Exception in thread "Thread-146" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/logging/Logger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:257)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.WsitPolicyResolver.<clinit>(WsitPolicyResolver.java:62)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.WsitPolicyResolverFactory.doCreate(WsitPolicyResolverFactory.java:48)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.PolicyResolverFactory.create(PolicyResolverFactory.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:106)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at (class generated from wsdl)
    at (SOAP call)
```

I can't even find the named class anywhere, and there seems to be almost no reference to it on the net.

**EDIT** It's in jaxb-osgi.jar

Isn't this supposed to be provided by glassfish? Surely if I include it with my app it poses introduces a risk of conflict?

Comment: Hi would like to bring this question back up.  Unfortunately the wiki pages no longer work now that Oracle and Java.net have changed so drastically and I couldn't figure out the details (passed the paste -- which was very helpful).

So the situation is this, I have a Java Web Start Application that needs to call web services from the glassfish v3 server.  It seems 100% reproducible.

The problem is that the javaws (client jdk) is 2.1 but glassfish is 2.2.  Glassfish decides which jars to tell the web start application to load.  The resources the web start app are using include: jaxb-api-os

Comment: I came across the same problem. Did you ever manage to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The description of your problem and the steps to reproduce are not clear at all but GlassFish v3 bundles Metro 2.0 and [Metro 2.0 contains JAX-WS 2.2, which clashes with the JAX-WS 2.1](http://blogs.oracle.com/ritzmann/entry/metro_2_0_on_java) that comes with Java SE 6:

> For a detailed analysis when exactly this is happening, see this [Wiki page](http://wikis.glassfish.org/metro/Wiki.jsp?page=Metro2.0OnJavaSE6). The reason for these failures is that Metro 2.0 contains JAX-WS 2.2, which clashes with JAX-WS 2.1 1 that is built into Java SE 6. You will only see these failures if you did not install Metro 2.0 with our installation scripts metro-on-glassfish.xml/metro-on-tomcat.xml. That is the case if you e.g. installed Metro 2.0 for GlassFish V3 via the update center or if you use a version of GlassFish V3 built into NetBeans.
>
> The simplest solution is to download the [Metro 2.0 nightly build](https://metro.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?expandFolder=7638&folderID=10314) and run the installation script. The script copies the file webservices-api.jar, which contains the JAX-WS 2.2 API, into `<java-home>/lib/endorsed`. Alternatively, you can of course manually copy `webservices-api.jar` into a suitable endorsed directory.

And because `com/sun/istack/logging/Logger` is [a dependency of JAX-WS 2.2](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=387973&tstart=0), you are very likely in the situation described in the mentioned [Wiki page](http://wikis.glassfish.org/metro/Wiki.jsp?page=Metro2.0OnJavaSE6):

> Metro 2.0 bundles JAX-WS 2.2. Java SE 6 contains JAX-WS 2.1 (SE 6 upgrade 3 and older version contain JAX-WS 2.0). That means Java will by default pick up the JAX-WS 2.1 APIs and implementation and code that exploits JAX-WS 2.2 features will not work.

Comment: That sounds like it might be related, but it sounds like glassfish v3 is broken in this case. I used the wsimport from glassfish v3 and deployed to that same server. I then ran the app client through webstart (Java 6) and "boom". That means this app client cannot be run by any standard j2se installation - which kinda misses the point of webstart. It may lead me to a solution however.

Comment: @Draemon The problem is not GlassFish v3, the problem is Java 6 and JAX-WS 2.2. So, because you're using JWS, I'd suggest to use the `wsimport` bundled with Java 6 for the client side in your case.